Failed to launch the browser process! spawn /opt/render/project/.cache/puppeteer/chrome, On Render Server
I deploy my project on Render (using Node.JS and ReactJS). I am using puppeteer to generate a receipt and download it to the computer. This functionality works perfectly on localhost, but when is deployed on the production website it doesn't work and throws the following error:
Error in Generating Receipt Error: Failed to launch the browser process!. spawn /opt/render/project/.cache/puppeteer/chrome ENOENT

I set a path for chrome in .env on Render like this:
CHROME_BIN: /opt/render/project/.cache/puppeteer/chrome
My PDF Generating function :
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  headless: true,
  args: ["--no-sandbox", "--disable-setuid-sandbox"],
  executablePath: process.env.CHROME_BIN || null,
});
// ....and so on

Please help to get rid of this error.

Please see Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors? and Error: Failed to launch the browser process puppeteer
